# Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[href=#]

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

My WordPress theme creates a Javascript error:

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[href=#tab-container]

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/read-this-first-wordpress-45-master-list/

I know that the problem is the character `#` and I have to escape it but I don't know how. Here's my code:

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab-container">>News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2-container">Reviews</a></li>
</ul>
```

```js
$(".tabs li").click(function() {
    $(".tabs li").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(".destination-tab").hide();
    var selected_tab = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    $(selected_tab).fadeIn();
    return false;
});
```

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Can you include the whole function? IMO the error is somewhere below the `...` where you use the `selected_tab`.

Comment: Do it like this. href="\"#tab-container\""

Comment: @RadekPech I added the whole function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code sample seems unrelated to the error message. However you can place special characters within an attribute selector in quotes, like this:

```
$('a[href="#tab-container"]');
```